# Implement JPA query with COUNT and SUM

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I want to implement JPA query using this SQL query:

```
String hql = "SELECT DATE(date) AS Date, SUM(volume) AS amount, COUNT(*) AS number_of_transactions " + 
                " FROM " + PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts.class.getName() + " WHERE (date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date )" + 
                " GROUP BY DATE(date)";
```

I tried this:

```
String hql = "SELECT DATE(e.date) AS Date, SUM(e.volume) AS amount, COUNT(e.*) AS count " + 
                " FROM " + PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts.class.getName() + " e WHERE (date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date )" + 
                " GROUP BY DATE(date)";
```

But I get error:

```
expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1, column 63 [SELECT DATE(e.date) AS Date, SUM(e.volume) AS amount, COUNT(e.*) AS count  FROM .......PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts e WHERE (date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date ) GROUP BY DATE(date)]
```

What is the proper way to implement this query into JPA?

Comment: Is there any answer you got? because this question's answers isn’t accepted yet, and you didn't respond too. I need about this information too please

Comment: See the below one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL doesn't know what `*` means.  You'd instead just say `e`, not `e.*`.

```
String hql = "SELECT DATE(e.date) AS Date, SUM(e.volume) AS amount, COUNT(e) AS count " 
              + " FROM " + PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts.class.getName()
              + " e WHERE (date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date )" 
              + " GROUP BY DATE(date)";
```

This is because JPQL operates on the *Java* entities.  Note that you are saying from a class name, not a table.  Objects don't have wildcards saying any field in the class.  Instead, you specify that the object itself is not null to say that a row is there.

The `e.*` syntax in SQL is essentially (although perhaps not literally) saying that there exists at least one non-null column on that row.  Because it doesn't have any more direct way of saying that a row exists.  But JPQL does have a way to say that an object exists.  That's a basic Java not-null check.  So in JPQL, you do it the Java way (albeit in JPQL syntax) rather than the SQL way.

See also

- [What does * mean in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38662318/6660678)
- [Why "SELECT c" instead of "SELECT *" in JPQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34725802/6660678)